# How to apply custom filters on image?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm using OpenCV4 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on WSL + XServer for GUI.

I want to create custom convlutional filter kernels and apply them to my image. this is the code I've written for it:

```
cv::Mat filter2D(cv::Mat input, cv::Mat filter)
{
    using namespace cv;
    Mat dst = input.clone();
    //cout << " filter data successfully found.  Rows:" << filter.rows << " cols:" << filter.cols << " channels:" << filter.channels() << "\n";
    //cout << " input data successfully found.  Rows:" << input.rows << " cols:" << input.cols << " channels:" << input.channels() << "\n";

    for (int i = 0-(filter.rows/2);i<input.rows-(filter.rows/2);i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0-(filter.cols/2);j<input.cols-(filter.cols/2);j++)
        {  //adding k and l to i and j will make up the difference and allow us to process the whole image
            float filtertotal = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < filter.rows;k++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < filter.rows;l++)
                {
                    if(i+k >= 0 && i+k < input.rows && j+l >= 0 && j+l < input.cols)
                    {  //don't try to process pixels off the edge of the map
                        float a = input.at<uchar>(i+k,j+l);
                        float b = filter.at<float>(k,l);
                        float product = a * b;
                        filtertotal += product;
                    }
                }
            }
            //filter all proccessed for this pixel, write it to dst
            dst.at<uchar>(i+(filter.rows/2),j+(filter.cols/2)) = filtertotal;
        }
    }
    return dst;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Declare variables
    cv::Mat_<float> src;
    const char* window_name = "filter2D Demo";
    // Loads an image
    src = cv::imread("fapan.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE ); // Load an image
    if( src.empty() )
    {
        printf(" Error opening image\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    static float x[3][3] = {
        {-1, -1, -1},
        {-1,  8, -1},
        {-1, -1, -1}
    };
    cv::Mat kernel(3,3, CV_16FC1, x);
    // Apply filter
    filter2D(src, kernel);
    cv::imshow( window_name, src );
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

the problem is that the output image is like this.
[image]

as you can see not only the edges are white, but also inside of it is white too.

the input image
[image]

Comment: scale your image to 0-255 range for unsigned byte data type and 0 to 1 for float data type. otherwise your image will be white

Comment: @user8190410 thanks for helping. i'm beginner. can u give me more info and tell me how can I do this?

Comment: What is the input image?

Comment: The Laplacian produces values outside the input range, including negative values. You need to apply a linear mapping to bring the result values into the standard range that `cv::imshow` expects.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I did this `src.convertTo(dst, CV_8UC1);` but when I do it before imshow, it only displays the grayscale normal image instead of showing the edges

Comment: In this line: `dst.at<uchar>(i+(filter.rows/2),j+(filter.cols/2)) = filtertotal;` you are assigning a floating-point value to an 8-bit integer. The float value could be negative, or could be larger than 255. This is where things go wrong.

Comment: You are adding the filter contributions, whereas I believe you should multiply instead.

Answer (score -1):

The output you have posted for the input code is correct as you are applying a normal filter on a image .

It may cause a little blurring or sharpening in it but it will never cause it to completely detect edges.

In order to detect only the edges along the images you must apply Laplacian along a certain direction.
[https://www.l3harrisgeospatial.com/docs/LaplacianFilters.html#:~:text=A%20Laplacian%20filter%20is%20an,an%20edge%20or%20continuous%20progression](https://www.l3harrisgeospatial.com/docs/LaplacianFilters.html#:%7E:text=A%20Laplacian%20filter%20is%20an,an%20edge%20or%20continuous%20progression). ( A link with some info )
Which is the derivative of the image it will only detect the change .

I recommend you do this on matlab image processing toolbox .